# Multiple urls point to same application with query strings

Tags: iis

I have 2 domain name, let's say www.contoso.com and www.contoso.de ,  and in my IIS, i have 1 web app and it should take this request as

www.contoso.com -> www.internal.com?l=en

www.contoso.de -> www.internal.com?l=de

What's the best practice for this and rewrite all html anchors ( a href ) as appropriate  ?

Comment: IIS can host websites written in many different technologies and languages. If you're looking for something built into those technologies or languages, we'd need to know which ones you're using. If, instead, you're looking for a purely IIS based solution, you're probably looking for [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/planning-for-arr/using-the-application-request-routing-module), but then you're probably off topic for a programming questions site.

Comment: I have ASP.NET web applications which is based on C#. This is achieved by Application Request Routing ?